# LINQ to SQL - filtering by distance between item's previous and next?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an application with mobile clients, where I receive positions from the users every x seconds. Due to safety reasons I need to store these positions server-side, but unfortunately it makes many requests slow (up to 60 seconds for a simple answer...).

I'm looking for an in-SQL solution for the following filter (which could be solved, of course, in non-SQL, non-LINQ ways, but I simply can't wrap my head around this):

The entries are sorted by DateTime. Each entry has at least 10 seconds between themselves and the next entry. The entries store DbGeography position data along with the timestamp (and of course, the user Id too). The response created from these entries should be filtered in a way that if `x[n+1]`'s location is not further from `x[n]`'s location (where `x[n]` is the nth element of the sequence, beginning with `x[0]` and `x[1]` as the first pair to be checked), then `x[n+1]` is discarded and not sent back, and the same check is re-run for `x[n+2]` and `x[n]`.

Distance should be configurable.

Basically I want to write the following code, in LINQ to SQL:

```cs
var finalItems = new List<X>();
foreach(var item in dbItems) {
    if(finalItems.Count == 0)
        finalItems.Add(item);
    else 
        if(finalItems.Last().Position.Distance(item.Position) > positionFilter)
            finalItems.Add(item);
}
```

Is there a way to do this in LINQ?

Comment: Since you are running `Distance` method in your application, even if you express this filter in LINQ to SQL, I guess EF would not be able to run all the filter in SQL.

Comment: What is `Distance` doing? You have two options: Have `Distance` return an `IQueryable` that EF can translate into SQL, or implement it in a stored procedure. Then write something like `items.Where(item => sp_Distance(items.First(), item) < filter)`

Comment: `Distance` is the built-in function of `DbGeography` - as far as I know it can be directly translated to SQL commands, at least that's the reason why it's in the Entity Framework package's Spatial namespace.

Comment: Linq won't make it any better. You code is fine, except that it could be a bit more efficient by not taking `finalItems.Last()` each time, but just memorizing the last item.

Comment: My goal would be to do this filtering purely in SQL, but it seems like the only option would be a stored procedure.